# Magento2: catalog_product_view.xml

Tags: magento2, catalog

Here what happen I am trying to add my custom phtml file in catalog_product_view.xml.

Underneath:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
<!--My custom container-->
  <container name="product.info.extension" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-extension" before="product.info.price">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.extension.layout" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/customattributes.phtml" after="page.main.title"> </block>
  </container>
<!----------------------->
```

phtml called proper.
But what happen Review tab removed. Once I add this custom phtml.

Can please anyone tell me what I did wrong here.

Comment: What is the location of your catalog_product_view.xml?

Comment: In my custom theme:app/design/frontend/custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: Can you post the whole file content?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have resolved this. I take name="reviews.tab" from the vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml. And it get resolved.

Comment: Post your answer and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have added additional Block name="reviews.tab" here:

```
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
```